# Correctly debugging IPhone Apps on XCode

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

The line below has an error, can you see it with a naked eye?

```
NSString *title = [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
NSString *newText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:"%@ button pressed.", title];
```

When the Iphone simulator executes this line it **crashes without any other information**. I must be missing something about debugging. The console showed me nothing.

I was able to figure out the error, **my question is not about that**. My question is why I get a hard crash with no help from XCode. Without any clue it took me precious 5 minutes before I could realize my typo.

Any suggestions? Or when programming for IPhone I just need to be very careful with typos?

EDIT: I guess some people did not see it immediately like me. The error is the lack of '@' for the string constant. So now my question is why XCode/Simulator did not show me any kind of error message, just crashed without any clues. **Am I missing something about debugging?**

Comment: What is the value of `title` before the line is executed?

Comment: enlighten us to the error please - I'm sure not going to start up xcode, paste the code, ...... to find out.

Comment: I added the value of title to the code.

Comment: This could be a question that leads to some useful information about using the Xcode debugger, but as-is, it seems to be just a pissy little rant.  I'd suggest rewriting it as an actual question.

Comment: as an analogous question, what happens when you forget the '*' on a char pointer in printf in 'C'? (or sprintf to make the analogy more correct)

Comment: @Kristopher: please read my question again, specially the edit part. It is very clear. Just trying to figure out whether i am missing something about the debugger. It is not a rant.

Comment: You should have gotten a warning on that line. Unfortunately I'm not at a Mac, so I can't verify that I get a warning.

Comment: if this takes 10 minutes to find then you should not code for iphone. u should find this even not running the code, just to see the warnings more carefully.

Comment: always turn on as many warnings as you can stand under the build options, one needs all the help one can get ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objective-C does not strongly verify that the arguments you pass to messages are of the right type during compilation nor at runtime. It should gives you a warning though.  Here you pass a c string instead of a NSString.  Because NSString are objects (thus referenced using pointer), your method uses it as a pointer while you feed it with a simple string.  You then probably try to access unaccessible memory blocks...

Comment: Thanks. I guess I am not missing anything and this is how it should work. Hard crash. Not even the line where it hard crashes is given. I had to use breakpoints. This questions is just to realize whether I have to get used to this painful debugging process or if there are better ways to debug that on XCode.

Comment: I'm curious why you did not received any warning.  I typed your code in Xcode on my machine just to be sure and it gave me a "warning: passing argument 1 of 'initWithFormat:' from incompatible pointer type" warning.

Answer (score 3):

I think you miss a `@` before the "%@ button pressed".
The correct one should be:

`NSString *newText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ button pressed.", title];`

All the constant NSString should be `@"SOMETHING HERE";`

Comment: Ok. Nice eye. But the question is why I get no help from XCode/Simulator to spot that bug. It just hard crashes. Am I missing something about debugging on XCode / Simulator?

Comment: downvotes are inappropriate, since the OP wouldn't tell us the error, this is good information.

Comment: why this is downvoted? "can you see it with a naked eye" is ended with a question mark and the ans is made before the EDIT in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Check you compilation warnings. That's all you need. On the case you are showing, you will get a proper warning that will alert you that bad things might happen at that line.

Answer (score 1):

I get the following Error when compiling your code:

```
error: cannot convert 'const char*' to 'NSString*' in argument passing
```

Not sure what you need to do to get it to show you that, I'm working in Obj-C++.

Try adding "-Wall" to your ["OtherWarningFlags"](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) under your target's build settings.

Comment: I get the warning, but not the error. When the app crashes it does not tell me the line where it crashed. So I guess that is expected. I just need to look for warnings and be very careful with memory crashes. Coming from Java that's not natural, but I can live with that.

Comment: 'not natural' would be a misnomer.  a different level of interaction with the machine by your programming language will make errors and warnings from the compiler far more 'important'.  the fact that you ignored a warning about pointers is your first and greatest learning experience while developing at this level.  heed these messages in the future.  the debugger is not at fault here, the Debugger is :)

Comment: glad I could help.  Obj-C is definitely a different monster, and take my advice - don't try a program in Obj-C++!!  That really messes stuff up.